# Display json data in html table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to display json data in html table using jQuery ? and How can i remove case sensitive while searching the result?

expected output

[image]
How can i display the result in my table? How can i achieve this?

```js
var data = [{
    "username": "John Doe",
    "email": "jn@gmail.com",
    "skills": "java,c,html,css"
  },
  {
    "username": "Jane Smith",
    "email": "js@gmail.com",
    "skills": "java,sql"
  },
  {
    "username": "Chuck Berry",
    "email": "cb@gmail.com",
    "skills": "vuejs"
  }
];



/* Get Result */
function getResult() {
  /* Read value from input fields */
  var skills = $("#skills").val() || '',
    email = $("#email").val() || '',
    username = $("#username").val() || '';

  var result = [],
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if ((skills !== '' && data[i]["skills"].indexOf(skills) !== -1) || (data[i]["email"] === email) || (
        data[i]["username"] === username)) {
      result.push(data[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
};

$('#submit').click(function onClick() {
  var output = getResult();
  console.log(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="skills" type="text" placeholder="skills">
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="mail id">
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: To do case-insensitive matches, compare `str1.toUpperCase() == str2.toUpperCase()`. What have you already tried to display your results as a table? Try starting with `jqueryObject.append()`

Comment: why are your creating loop in data? if in skill write C and in Email write jn@gmail.com , your code return first data !! what's your goal ?

Comment: @barzin.A It's advance search.Suppose if I search for **c** it should display  the users with skill set of C. It's like you can search using any one field. In the displayed result you will be having another search option where you can filter the data according to requirement. Yeah i have noticed the issue which you have raised. need to figure it out with the solution. In that case it should display error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a table and need to append coming data to this table using below code:-

```
$('#submit').click(function onClick() {
  var output = getResult();
  var html = '';
  $.each(output,function(key,value){
      html +='<tr>';
      html +='<td>'+ value.username + '</td>';
      html +='<td>'+ value.email + '</td>';
      html +='<td>'+ value.skills + '</td>';
      html +='</tr>';
  });
$('table tbody').html(html);
});
```

To do case-insensitive comparison use `.toUpperCase()`

Working snippet:-

```js
var data = [{
    "username": "John Doe",
    "email": "jn@gmail.com",
    "skills": "java,c,html,css"
  },
  {
    "username": "Jane Smith",
    "email": "js@gmail.com",
    "skills": "java,sql"
  },
  {
    "username": "Chuck Berry",
    "email": "cb@gmail.com",
    "skills": "vuejs"
  }
];



/* Get Result */
function getResult() {
  /* Read value from input fields */
  var skills = $("#skills").val() || '',
    email = $("#email").val() || '',
    username = $("#username").val() || '';

  var result = [],
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if ((skills !== '' && data[i]["skills"].toUpperCase().indexOf(skills.toUpperCase()) !== -1) || (data[i]["email"].toUpperCase() === email.toUpperCase()) || (
        data[i]["username"].toUpperCase() === username.toUpperCase())) {
      result.push(data[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
};

$('#submit').click(function onClick() {
  var output = getResult();
  var html = '';
  $.each(output,function(key,value){
      html +='<tr>';
      html +='<td>'+ value.username + '</td>';
      html +='<td>'+ value.email + '</td>';
      html +='<td>'+ value.skills + '</td>';
      html +='</tr>';
  });
$('table tbody').html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="skills" type="text" placeholder="skills">
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="mail id">
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">

<br>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Email ID</th>
      <th>Core Skills</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to remove case sensitive while searching the data?

Comment: I have more doubt regarding the search, like if i search according to one input it's showing the result, like if i enter input 1 as c and username as Chuck Berry, it's taking the first input to search. Actually the Chuck Berry doesn't have skill of c, so it should display error no results found. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data-table jQuery plugin to generate table from `json`directly like

```
$('#tableId').DataTable({
    data: jsonData,
    columns: [
        { data: 'username',title:'Username'},
        { data: 'emailId',title:'EmailId'}, 
        { data: 'skils',title:'Core Skills'}
    ],
    "search": {
      "caseInsensitive": false
    }
});
```

For More detail follow Data-table jQuery Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```js
var data = [{
        "username": "John Doe",
        "email": "jn@gmail.com",
        "skills": "java,c,html,css"
    },
    {
        "username": "Jane Smith",
        "email": "js@gmail.com",
        "skills": "java,sql"
    },
    {
        "username": "Chuck Berry",
        "email": "cb@gmail.com",
        "skills": "vuejs"
    }
];

function BindDataToTable(d,obj){
  var keys=Object.keys(d[0]);
  var table=document.createElement("table");
  var trHead=document.createElement("tr");
  jQuery(keys).each((index,item)=>{
    var th=document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML=item;
    trHead.appendChild(th)
  })
   table.appendChild(trHead)
   for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++){
   var tr=document.createElement("tr");
  jQuery(keys).each((index,item)=>{
    var td=document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML=d[i][item];
    tr.appendChild(td)
  })
   table.appendChild(tr)
   }
   
   jQuery(obj).append(table);
}
BindDataToTable(data,"#tableElement")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="skills" type="text" placeholder="skills">
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="mail id">
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">

<div id="tableElement">
</div>
```