# Create data table from API data - javascript, JQuery, ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a table from an API using jQuery in JavaScript, I'm brand new to the language and it's unclear to me how to access the data that is returned from the `.ajax` query.

In the code below I am able to fetch the data and return it in the console but when I try to set it to a variable to use to visualize I am getting the error:

> "<a class='gotoLine' href='#65:39'>65:39</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Is there a step I am missing to set the `data` variable to something I can access outside of the fetch request?

Here is my code:

## HTML

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>County</th>
      <th>Percent Immunized</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="vaxData">
```

## JS

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://health.data.ny.gov/resource/nvtm-yit2.json",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      "$limit" : 5000,
      "$$app_token" : "aGFbKDOg0gCeCm2c9Od2EsFjL"
    }
}).done(function(data) {
  alert("Retrieved " + data.length + " records from the dataset!");
  console.log(data);
  
  return data
});

var vaxData = document.getElementById(data);
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jconoranderson/bgk3Lvx5/25/

Comment: Hi John, please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399080/display-json-data-in-html-table-using-jquery

Comment: in the 'done(callback)' you are receiving the data, but you are not storing it anywhere. Either you process your data and then present it to the view (as @rajatJha showed you) or you store it in a variable outside the scope of the callback, so that it can be accessed later. Plus, getElementById accepts a string, not a set of data.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering, is how to store it.

Comment: save any database

Comment: The problem I am having with that example though is that it is using a newly declared variable to create the 'data'. What I am trying to understand is how to take the data that is returned from the fetch command and put it into a variable that can be used elsewhere in the script.

Comment: How else would you want to use the data other than updating the table?

Comment: Thanks Ben, where I'm really having trouble is creating a variable outside of the initial connection to the API that I can use to access the data. If you check out the fiddle you'll see that I have tried creating a function to store the data as a variable but I'm still getting an error that the `function is not defined`.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is take `return data` and put that into a variable I can use elsewhere. After that I can start to look at the html etc.

Comment: But do you need to 'store' the data or could you just use it to update the table and then forget about it?

Comment: I ultimately want to use it to create visualizations so once the data is stored in an object I can use elsewhere I will have a lot more options. New fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jconoranderson/bgk3Lvx5/45/

Comment: Does the answer I've given below help at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253160/discussion-between-john-conor-and-ben-stephens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error that you get relates to this line:

```
var vaxData = document.getElementById(data);
```

As there is no data variable in [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) here.

You may be thinking that returning a value from the done callback would populate this variable, but it won't because it's in a different scope (which you could fix by declaring var data before the `$.ajax` call) and it happens at a different time and context. The execution of the javascript won't wait for the done callback to finish and `var vaxData = document.getElementById(data);` will run before `alert("Retrieved " + data.length + " records from the dataset!");` will run. A better explanation for this sort of thing can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing).

Also, `document.getElementById()` expects a string not an array like the data returned from the API should be.

To resolve this issue you could declare the `data` variable before the call to `$.ajax` and execute the update of the table in the done callback function. In the example below, I've used the a function called `update_table` to do this and I've called `data` `vaccination_data`.

One other issue is the HTML for the table is not completed in your example.

```js
var vaccination_data = [];

$.ajax({
  url: "https://health.data.ny.gov/resource/nvtm-yit2.json",
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    "$limit" : 5000,
    "$$app_token" : 'your_app_token'
  }
}).done(function(api_data) {
  vaccination_data = api_data;
  update_table();
});

var vaxData = document.getElementById('vaxData');

const cell_keys = ['city', 'county', 'percentcompletelyimmunized'];

function create_element(tag, attributes, children = []) {
  const element = Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), attributes);
  element.append(...children);
  return element;
}

function create_row_element(item) {
  return create_element(
    'tr', {},
    cell_keys.map( (key) => create_element('td', { innerHTML: item[key] }) )
  );
}

function update_table() {
  vaxData.innerHTML = '';
  vaxData.append(...vaccination_data.map(create_row_element));
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>County</th>
      <th>Percent Immunized</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="vaxData"></tbody>
</table>
```

Edit to add, this line: `vaccination_data = api_data;` also uses something called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to work so that the done callback function has a reference to the `vaccination_data` variable.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I appreciate your detailed response. Though when I try to run this in jsfiddle I am now getting the error: `"<a class='gotoLine' href='#52:1'>52:1</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`. I am trying to debug before I finally accept, I'm still learning how to discern .js errors. I'm used to python where it identifies the exact line...

Comment: Are you including jQuery in the new fiddle?

Comment: Ah, never mind! I was running it in pure javascript. Thanks so much for your help and patience. I'm very new to javascript.

Comment: One more question @Ben Stephens. If I wanted to access the data in the table as an object. How would I go about that? The vaxData function for example returns a. ot more information than just a json object containing the data...

Comment: @JohnConor I don't think I understand the question. `vaxData` is a variable containing a reference to an HTMLElement object. By "If I wanted to access the data in the table as an object." do you mean the data you've retrieved from the API or the contents of the cells of the table (or something else)?

Comment: Apologies, I'm approaching this with my python hat on. What I'm trying to achieve over and above the table is a `var` that is an object containing the `json` data. Something I can access elements of and use the data to produce visualizations, etc. Something similat to a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @JohnConor `vaccination_data` contains the data from the API, it's used in the code above in the `update_table` function to create the table rows and cells, but any function with access to the `vaccination_data` variable could use this.

Comment: Got it, thanks! You have been incredibly helpful. Thank you for your time.